# Scroll reveal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollreveal.js

Im trying to use scrollReveal.js after reading [THIS](https://www.sitepoint.com/revealing-elements-scrollreveal-js/) tutorial and using their code, i still cant get my divs to fade in when my viewport is on them.

**Html**

```
<head>
<script src="scrollreveal-master/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div data-sr>This is the first div</div>
<div data-sr>This is the second div</div>
<div data-sr>This is yet another div</div>
```

**javascript**

```
new scrollReveal();
```

When i view the console on my web page it says

"*Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollReveal is not defined*"

Comment: Are you getting any other errors like a 404 error? Where is your code? Does it come *after* you load `scrollreveal.min.js`? Also, that site appears to have a typo. It should be `new ScrollReveal()`

Comment: I am only getting one error (the "reference error"). And my code is at the end of my body tag and i load scrollReveal at the start of my head.

Comment: @RhysEdwards Try to load the library before your script at the end of the page

Comment: I am doing that, i load the library at the top of the page in the head.

Comment: @RhysEdwards Read my comment "try at the end, before your script".

Comment: Tried and didn't work. My javascript is external by the way.

Comment: look in the console in the network tab if you haven't a 404 error for the request of the script

Comment: No 404 Error. its something to do with my scrollReveal function i think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this to add an animation on scroll using scrollReveal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />


</head>

<body>

<div id="main">

<div data-sr> one </div>
<div data-sr> two </div>
<div data-sr> three </div>

</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@3.3.2/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Changing the defaults
window.sr = ScrollReveal({ reset: true });

// Customizing a reveal set
sr.reveal('div', {opacity: 0.9,duration:3000});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Working example : https://plnkr.co/edit/qC33zle0fafyAL0RjkVl?p=preview